# Probability of winning a book

Tags: probability

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. The statement is:

Lucas and Monk play chess. The first to win a match gets a book as a reward. Each match can be won, lost or a tie. The probability of there being $k$ matches until anyone wins is $\frac{1}{2^{k+2}}, k=1,2,...$. Lucas' chance of winning the book is twice that of Monk. What is the probability that Monk will win the book?

I know I should get $\frac{1}{3}$ for Monk's chance, since either Lucas or Monk must get the book (the matches go on until someone wins), and their chances should add up to $1$. This reasoning is not what I'm asked for, though - I must somehow derive this from the immediate data.

My attempt has been:

$P(M_i)$: Probability of Monk winning the ith match.

$P(L_i)$: Probability of Lucas winning the ith match.

$P(T_i)$: Probability of the ith match being a tie.

$$P(M_i) = P(M_i | T_{i-1}) \cdot P(T_{i-1}) = P(M)\cdot P(T_{i-1})$$

where $P(M)$ is the probability of Monk winning a match - which I take to be the same for any match.

I am told that

$$ P(T_{i-1}) = \frac{1}{2^{k+2}}, $$

and Monk's chance of winning the book is the sum of his chances of winning every match:

$$ P(Monk\ gets\ book) = P(M) + \sum_{i=2}^\infty P(M) \cdot P(T_{i-1}) $$
$$ = P(M) \cdot [ 1 + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{i+2}} ] $$
$$ = P(M) \cdot [1 + \frac14 \sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac1{2^i} ] $$
$$ = P(M) \cdot [1 + \frac14 (-\frac12 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{2^i})] $$
$$ = P(M) \cdot [1 + \frac14 (-\frac12 + 1)] $$
$$ = \frac98P(M)$$

And by the same steps $P(Lucas\ gets\ book) = \frac98 P(L) $.

But on each match:

$$ P(M) + P(L) + P(T_i | T_{i-1}) = 1 $$

$$P(T_i | T_{i-1}) = \frac{P(T_i\ and\ T_{i-1})}{P(T_{i-1})} = \frac{P(T_i)}{P(T_{i-1})} = \frac{2^{-(i+1)-2}}{2^{-i-2}} = \frac12 $$

So that $P(L) = 1 - \frac12 - P(M) = \frac12 - P(M)$.

And I am told that $P(Lucas\ gets\ book) = 2 \cdot P(Monk\ gets\ book)$

$$ \frac98P(L) = \frac98[\frac12 - P(M)] = 2 \cdot \frac98 P(M) $$
$$ \rightarrow P(M) = \frac16 $$

$$ P(Monk\ gets\ book) = \frac3{16} $$

But $ P(Lucas\ gets\ book) = \frac38 $ so that:

$$ P(Monk\ gets\ book) + P(Lucas\ gets\ book) = \frac9{16} \neq 1 $$

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for reading through!

Comment: Is it the exact statement from your exercise? I'm slightly confused by the sentence *"The probability of there being k matches until anyone wins is [...]"*... Namely, if you define $p_k$ as the probability that there are exactly $k$ ties (before a $(k+1)$-th game where someone wins), then one should have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k = 1$.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it again and the statement is exactly that. At the time I didn't pay it attention since it was a given, but I see your point. Do you believe if the $p_k$ is changed then the answer would be coherent?

Comment: try it with $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2^{k+2}}$

Comment: With $\frac1{2^{k+1}}$ I get $P(Monk\ gets\ book) = \frac5{24}$ and $P(Lucas\ gets\ book) = \frac56$ which add up to $\frac{25}{24}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that either of the two gets the book is  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over 2^{k+2}}={1\over4}$. With probability ${3\over4}$ the game will go on forever, and the book will not be handed out at all. It follows that Monk gets the book with probability ${1\over12}$.

In your own argument you do not clearly distinguish between the events $T_n:=\bigl\{n$ games played, and all were ties$\bigr\}$ and $R_{n+1}:=\bigl\{(n+1)^{\rm st}$ game is a tie $\bigm|T_n\bigr\}$. Put
$$q_n:= P[T_n], \qquad p_n:=P[R_n]\ .$$
Then $q_0=1$, and we have the following recursions:
$$q_{n+1}=p_{n+1}\cdot q_n, \quad q_n\cdot(1-p_{n+1})={1\over 2^{n+3}}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
Looking at the appearing numbers for small $n$ one conjectures and then proves by induction that
$$p_n=1-{1\over 3\cdot 2^n +2},\quad q_n={3\over4}+{1\over 2^{n+2}}\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$

Comment: I see! This makes sense, but shouldn't I get those same results with what I did above?

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!